Reset text depth (or text height)
Here Align line with caption in Tikz pgfplot legend the legend alignment are wrong because of an entry that goes below the preset text depth=0.15em - see "default every axis legend style" on page 260 in the manual.
If the text depth is already set, how can it be unset? I tried text depth=false, text depth=none and text depth=\empty - of cause non of that worked.
MWE:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[text depth=0pt]
\node[draw=red, inner sep=0pt] {$\frac{1}{2}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Wanted output without removing [text depth=0pt]:


I know it has a lot of pages but sometimes the manual has the answers as well: When you write text height= without specifying anything, the “natural” size of the text box remains unchanged.

@Qrrbrbirlbel: Yes - I even looked at that page, but I did apparently not read it. I skimmed it and wrongly concluded there was no information to be gained. I could not imagine that ...= was even possible.

The code for text depth is
\tikzoption{text depth}{\def\tikz@text@depth{#1}}

and the initial value for \tikz@text@depth is empty.
Reset it locally to empty.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[text depth=0pt]
\node[draw=red, inner sep=0pt,text depth=] {$\frac{1}{2}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}



That is certainly a way to achieve the desired output. I feel that is would not always be possible to do it like that.

@hpekristiansen Do you like the simpler method I found?

Thanks - that was really simple

@hpekristiansen With a bit of luck, also.
